# Group by -having statement from mysql to oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have this statement, which works well in MySQL

```
SELECT r
  FROM (  SELECT MAX(recno) AS r,
                 f1,
                 f2,
                 f3,
                 f4,
                 f5,
                 f6,
                 f7,
                 f8,
                 COUNT(*) AS count2
            FROM mytable
        GROUP BY f1,
                 f2,
                 f3,
                 f4,
                 f5,
                 f6,
                 f7,
                 f8
          HAVING (count2 > 1)) tr
```

But does not work well in Oracle

> **ORA-00904: invalid identifier "count2"**

How can I make it run in Oracle?

Comment: Simply put `where count2 > 1)` outside the sub-query instead, at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

as you can't use alias.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(recno) as r
FROM mytable
GROUP BY f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

There is nothing "Oracle-specific" about writing the query this way.  It is just a simpler way to write the query that should work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r
  FROM (  SELECT MAX(recno) AS r,
                 f1,
                 f2,
                 f3,
                 f4,
                 f5,
                 f6,
                 f7,
                 f8,
                 COUNT(*) AS count2
            FROM mytable
        GROUP BY f1,
                 f2,
                 f3,
                 f4,
                 f5,
                 f6,
                 f7,
                 f8
          HAVING (count(*) > 1)) tr
```

Comment: It looks very similar to the previous answer

Comment: Probably we write answer in this same time - @Raphael was a first! :)